# ssh key permission denied failure

Tags: linux, unix, administrator

I have done so much of googling on this but just couldn't find the exact answer,there are many threads on this, all of them point to check for file permissions or `$HOME` directory which are right in my case, below are the details. Any tips on how to debug or resolve is really appreciated:

```
username@machine-linux2:~/.ssh$ ls -ld .
drwx------ 2 username users 0 Jan  4 23:00 .
username@machine-linux2:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "username@company.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/usr2/username/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
open /usr2/username/.ssh/id_rsa failed: Permission denied.
Saving the key failed: /usr2/username/.ssh/id_rsa.
```

Also on a side note, I am seeing some weird stuff on this machine,echo `$PATH` just gives the following, previously it used to lot more of paths, don't know what happened all of a sudden, the environment seems to be messed up:

```
username@machine:~/.ssh$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
```

Comment: Can you create a file in your `/usr2/username` folder? Does the touch command work? 

Also, did you modify your .bash_profile recently? Maybe you lost the PATH there

Did someone else login into your account (like a sys admin)? That could have changed permissions

Comment: @HobbesofCalvin - Touch command is not working,not able to create files,i have sudo permissions on this machine so I can control the permissions...something might have happend with bash_profile because each time I login previously it used to print some diagnostic info but now it prints none,not sure why?how can I fix this?

Comment: Also previously my terminal prompt used to look like <username:/usr2/username/.ssh> ,now it lookslike "username@machine:~/.ssh$",does anyone know why is this difference?

Comment: The easiest way to fix would be to run a `sudo chown -R u+rw /usr2/username/*` and then `sudo chmod -R u+rw /usr2/username/*`. Also, if your company has a backup restore your bash_profile, or maybe get it from someone in your team - usually folks on the same team have similar bash environments.

Comment: @HobbesofCalvin - Iget chown: invalid user: `u+rw' after running first sudo command...I checked  the "vi ~/.bash_profile "on a different machine which works fine,it doesnt anything important,so am not sure if bash_profile matters but the PATH variables are really different between working and non-working machines..is there a way I can copy the path

Comment: My bad - copy paste error :) 

The first command should be: `sudo chown -R username /usr2/username/*`

Comment: @HobbesofCalvin - I already have the correct permissions..any case I tried but it didnot help :-( still having the original problem

Comment: @HobbesofCalvin - This is just so surprising..folder has the required permissions,right owner..not sure why ssh is failing ..something wrong with ssh?

Comment: If the file `id_rsa` already exists and it has a read-only permission, that may be causing it.

Comment: @HobbesofCalvin - no..it doesnt exist.. ".ssh" directory is empty

Comment: Make sure the .ssh directory is writeable and executable by your user.

Comment: @HobbesofCalvin - I already shared this info in my question,username@machine-linux2:~/.ssh$ ls -ld .
drwx------ 2 username users 0 Jan  4 23:00 .

Comment: The only other thing I can think of at 1:24 am is that your machine is under attack, and someone has modified the ssh-gen and sh binaries itself. This would be especially true since your bash_profile decided to go weird all of a sudden.

Comment: @HobbesofCalvin - Magic of a restart restored back the system but I still dont understand what could have happened

Comment: LOL! That should be marked the correct answer, and all my other suggestions as the things to try before you reboot.

Comment: Check the permissions on your $HOME (`ls -ld ~`), check that you really are who you think you are (`whoami`, `who am i`, `who`). Check that your `~/.profile`, `~/.bash*` don't contain anything strange (something added aliases/fuctions if normal commands now misbehave). Try to use them explicitly (e.g., `/bin/touch`).